# Simple way to cancel user input on esc key pressed?

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

Is there a simple way to cancel the user input in a JTextField when key <kbd>Esc</kbd> is pressed ?

I mean something different that a key listener and a data backup.

Thanks

Comment: everything you are recommended to do is _different_ from a KeyListener ;-) use keybindings - and add some logic that restores the possibly edited text in the field to the text at the last commit/load

Comment: I didn't knox the KeyBindings. It looks more efficient that keylistener, but not "that" different

Comment: first look might not reveal all its power, it's definitely _much_ different ;-)

Answer (score 0):

[Add](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#addKeyListener%28java.awt.event.KeyListener%29) a [KeyListener](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyListener.html) to your JTextField:

```
JTextField field = new JTextField.addKeyListener(yourKeyListener);
```

where yourKeyListener could be:

```
public class YourKeyListener implements KeyListener{
    void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
         Component source = e.getSource();
         if (source instanceof JTextField && e.getId() == KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE ){

             JTextField f = (JTextField) source;
             f.setText("");

         }
    }
}
```

Comment: @kleopatra: could you explain at least why shouldn't use keylistener?

Comment: This would make a good question; but, for me, maintainability is the major limitation of `KeyListener`.

Comment: the general rule is (which I have mentioned more than once :-) Do use for the highest abstraction available

Answer (score 0):

`CancelAction`, discussed [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textfield.html) and shown [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/TextFieldDemoProject/src/components/TextFieldDemo.java), is an example that uses [`Action`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html) and a [key binding](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html).

Comment: Yeah, but this Action is just resetting someting to "". I want to reset it to the value before first edit.

Comment: You'll have to keep track of the unedited value, perhaps in your application's data model.

Comment: @user777466 - looks like you either didn't completely read or didn't completely understand my comment, repeating myself: "add some logic that restores the possibly edited text in the field to the text of the last commit/load"