# How to listen esc key on terminal?

Tags: java

i'm making a program without GUI, and i want catch the ESC key when is pressed for cancel a input (using Scanner).

I'm searching on google an here but i just found for SWING

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4005574/java-key-listener-in-commandline

Comment: And I don't think is possible because cli applications don't have knowledge of what key code was pressed. I wonder what others will say.

Comment: have a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7173674/simple-way-to-cancel-user-input-on-esc-key-pressed/7173807#7173807

Answer (score 0):

[JLine](http://jline.sourceforge.net/) may help.  It is a third party library and has its own native code, but I don't think there's a way to read ESC from the console in java using standard API.